# In jQuery how do I get an id from an attribute if I can't use 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-plugins

Thank you for taking a look at my question which goes as follows:

I'm using a jQuery plugin called Inline [inline affirm](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Lightweight-Inline-Confirmation-Plugin-For-jQuery-Inline-Affirm.html) which basically just asks the user for a confirmation (yes or no) on the action they're performing.

**this is the basic usage of the plugin:**

HTML:

```
<li class="msg-li-delete" data-msgid="<?php echo $msg_id_att; ?>">
          <div class="affirm light"
               data-id="<?php echo $msg_id_att; ?>"
               data-title="delete"
               data-question="are you sure?" style="display:inline-block;"></div></li>
```

JS:

```
$(".affirm").inlineAffirm({
    callback : function(ele){
        var msg_id_conf = $(".affirm").attr("data-id");
        delete_private_msg(msg_id_conf);
      }
  });
```

The problem with this is that I'm trying to get a unique id from the anchor tag so I can call the `delete_private_msg` function and give the id as an argument, the `delete_private_msg` function  will do some ajax interactions with PHP to delete the message.

It doesn't matter on which anchor I click the item that's deleted is always the first one.

**So I tried this:**

```
  $(".affirm").inlineAffirm({
      var thisid = $(this).attr("data-id");
        callback : function(ele){
            var msg_id_conf = thisid;
            delete_private_msg(msg_id_conf);
          }
      });
```

But I get the following error in console:

> 126 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I really hope it's understandable.

Comment: Try ele.data("id")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its working, but if the callback is called in the onclick handler, then this should work

```
$(".affirm").inlineAffirm({
    callback : (ele) => {
        var msg_id_conf = $(this).attr("data-id");
        delete_private_msg(msg_id_conf);
      }
  });
```

NOTE: This is an ES6 feature

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question, but to get the ID of a an element with jquery you can do the following:

```
$( ".affirm" ).attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance `msg_id_conf` and `thisid` are different types of variables (like one is a `String` and the other an `Int`)?

Else, does this work?

```
  $(".affirm").inlineAffirm({
    callback : function(ele){
        var msg_id_conf = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id"));
        delete_private_msg(msg_id_conf);
      }
  });
```

If neither of these work, could you please paste the full html tag from class "affirm"?

UPDATE

Try this way then:

```
  $(".affirm").inlineAffirm({
    var thisid = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id"));
    callback : function(ele){
        var msg_id_conf = thisid;
        delete_private_msg(msg_id_conf);
      }
  });
```

Comment: HTML added, please give it a check. Thanks.